# hibernate. How to add unique index for field combination?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, constraints, unique

I have following hibernate mapping:

```
@Entity
public class UserPattern {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "patern_id")
    Pattern pattern;

    ...
}
```

Does hibernate allow to add unique index that combination of `user` and `pattern` was unique ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it will works :

```
@Table(name="UserPattern", 
    uniqueConstraints=
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"user_id", ""})
```

or

```
@Table(name="UserPattern",  uniqueConstraints={
   @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"user_id", "patern_id"})
})
```

Comment: The value for annotation attribute Table.uniqueConstraints must be some @javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint annotation

Comment: Eclipse (like me) confuses annotation inside the annotation

Comment: That's a unique constraint - like SQL: "ADD CONSTRAINT UserPattern UNIQUE ...". But what about unique index - like SQL: "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UserPattern ON ..."?

Answer (score 4):

You may take a look at [`@NaturalId`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-naturalid):

> **5.1.8. Natural-id**
>
> Although we recommend the use of surrogate keys as primary keys, you should try to identify natural keys for all entities. A natural key is a property or combination of properties that is unique and non-null. It is also immutable. Map the properties of the natural key as `@NaturalId` or map them inside the `<natural-id>` element. Hibernate will generate the necessary unique key and nullability constraints and, as a result, your mapping will be more self-documenting.

Note however, the clause about immutability - this may not suit your use-case.

```
@Entity
public class UserPattern {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  Integer id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  @NaturalId
  User user;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "patern_id")
  @NaturalId
  Pattern pattern;

  ...
}
```